# Why I cannot find Blazorise scripts and it has not found content directory?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, blazorise

All done by https://blazorise.com/docs/start.

**DirectoryNotFoundException:** Could not find a part of the path `\wwwroot\_content`

Comment: remove the "\wwwroot\" this is the root directory.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: If you look at the docs you referenced they use "_content/Blazorise/..." other than that you need to share the code that causes the error.

Comment: See static assets under razor class libraries which is what Blazorise is. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you have another root path

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    WebRootPath = "wwwroot",
    Args = args
});
```

or use only

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

then

```
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
```